# Convert (Date + Time) from NSString to NSDate and Add Some Hours

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

Requirement is very simple.
I have a date+time in `2014-05-16 09:10am` format. I want to convert it in `NSDate` so that I can add/remove few hours to get a time span for some calculation.
What exactly dateFormat should I use while converting this `NSString` value into `NSDate` ? I have tried following

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm a"];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm a"];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm"];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm a"];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm ZZZZ"];
```

I searched on SO but couldn't get the exact answer. I tried mentioned solutions too by molding them according to my requirement but no gain so far. So I'm posting my query here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your Hours HH - 24 hours format && hh - 12 hours format .

According to your input date String, This is working fine

```
 NSString* strdate = @"2014-05-16 09:10am";

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mma"];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:strdate];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 NSString* dateString = "2014-05-16 09:10am";
NSDateFormatter* formt = [NSDateFormatter new];
[formt setDateFormat:"yyyy-MM-dd  hh:mma"];   //hh - for 12 hours format
NSDate* date = [formt dateFromString:dateString];

 NSLog(@"your date is ==%@",date);
```

if u need to add some hours

```
NSTimeInterval  InEightHours = 8 * 60 * 60;  //mutiple the hours with minutes
NSDate *dateHoursAhead = [date dateByAddingTimeInterval:InEightHours];

NSLog(@"your final date is ==%@", dateHoursAhead);
```

Comment: Your code returns nill for date. Might be because you are using time format"yyyy-MM-dd  hh:mm: a", instead of  "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mma". But yes, your code of adding Hours is working well. So I have vote up for this. Thanks.